# Incorrect row indices returned upon box select when only certain observations are plotted - Plotly, htmlWidgets, Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, plotly, htmlwidgets

I am writing a Shiny application in which a user has two slider Inputs - one for "fold change", the other for "p-value". There is a dataset that contains 10 observations that each of a fold change and p-value. Only the points that have a p-value less than the "p-value" slider input, and a fold change greater than the "fold change" slider input are plotted at a given time.

What I have written so far is provided below -

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sliderInput("threshP", "P-value:", min = 0, max = 1, value=0.05, step=0.05),
  sliderInput("threshFC", "Fold change:", min = 0, max = 10, value=5, step=0.5),
  plotlyOutput("plot1"),
  textOutput("selectedValues")
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  set.seed(1)
  threshP <- reactive(input$threshP)
  threshFC <- reactive(input$threshFC)

  dat <- data.frame(ID = paste0("ID",1:10), FC=runif(10,0,10), pval=runif(10,0,1))
  dat$ID <- as.character(dat$ID)

  # x-axis FC, y-axis pval
  xMax = max(dat$FC)
  xMin = min(dat$FC)
  yMax = max(dat$pval)
  yMin = min(dat$pval)

  df <- data.frame()
  p <- ggplot(df) + geom_point() + xlim(xMin, xMax) + ylim(yMin, yMax)
  gp <- ggplotly(p)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    gp %>% onRender("
      function(el, x, data) {
      var dat = data.dat
      var selFC = [];
      var selP = [];
      dat.forEach(function(row){
        rowFC = row['FC']
        rowP = row['pval']
        if (rowP <= data.thP && data.thFC <= rowFC){
          selFC.push(rowFC);
          selP.push(rowP);
        }
      });

      var Traces = [];
      var tracePoints = {
        x: selFC,
        y: selP,
        mode: 'markers',
        marker: {
          color: 'black',
          size: 6
        },
      };
      Traces.push(tracePoints);
      Plotly.addTraces(el.id, Traces);

      var idRows = []
      for (a=0; a<data.dat.length; a++){
        idRows.push(data.dat[a]['ID'])
      }
      console.log(idRows)

      el.on('plotly_selected', function(e) {
        numSel = e.points.length
        Points = e.points
        selID = []
        for (a=0; a<numSel; a++){
          PN = Points[a].pointNumber
          selRow = idRows[PN]
          selID.push(selRow)
        }
        Shiny.onInputChange('selID', selID);
      })
      }", data = list(dat = dat, thP=threshP(), thFC=threshFC()))})

    selID <- reactive(input$selID)
    selDat <- reactive(dat[which(dat$ID %in% selID()), ])
    output$selectedValues <- renderPrint({str(selDat())})
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This is creating the correct output if all ten points are plotted (when the "p-value" slider is at 1, and the "fold-change" slider is at 0). For example, in the image below, all 10 data points are plotted, and the user selected one that has a p-value (y-axis) near the value of 1. Underneath the plot is the returned row, which has a fold-change (x-axis) value of 6.61 and a p-value (y-axis) value of 0.992. It seems to be working.

[image: Correct data frame rows returned if all 10 points are plotted]

However, incorrect output is given if *not* all ten points are plotted. For example, in the image below, only 6 data points are plotted, and the user selected one that has a p-value (y-axis) near the value of 1. Underneath the plot is the returned row, which has a fold-change (x-axis) value of 2.02 and a p-value (y-axis) value of 0.77. It does not seem to be working.

[image: Incorrect data frame rows returned when less than all 10 points are plotted]

I realize/believe the problem is occurring because when not all 10 points are plotted, then the returned row indices can only be between 1-c, where c is some number less than 10. So, the row indices no longer match up with the original data frame. However, I am lost at how to remedy this problem.

Any advice on how to solve this problem? Thank you.

EDIT:

Thanks to the helpful debugging suggestions, I think the problem may be solved. The trick is to use the pointNumber as the index in an array variable that contains the subset of the data frame being plotted. Here, that is the sselID object.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sliderInput("threshP", "P-value:", min = 0, max = 1, value=1, step=0.05),
  sliderInput("threshFC", "Fold change:", min = 0, max = 10, value=0, step=0.5),
  plotlyOutput("plot1"),
  verbatimTextOutput("selectedValues")
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  set.seed(1)
  threshP <- reactive(input$threshP)
  threshFC <- reactive(input$threshFC)

  dat <- data.frame(ID = paste0("ID",1:10), FC=runif(10,0,10), pval=runif(10,0,1))
  dat$ID <- as.character(dat$ID)
  print(dat)

  # x-axis FC, y-axis pval
  xMax = max(dat$FC)
  xMin = min(dat$FC)
  yMax = max(dat$pval)
  yMin = min(dat$pval)

  df <- data.frame()
  p <- ggplot(df) + geom_point() + xlim(xMin, xMax) + ylim(yMin, yMax)
  gp <- ggplotly(p)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    gp %>% onRender("
      function(el, x, data) {
      var dat = data.dat
      var selFC = [];
      var selP = [];
      var sselID = [];
      dat.forEach(function(row){
        rowFC = row['FC']
        rowP = row['pval']
        rowID = row['ID']
        if (rowP <= data.thP && data.thFC <= rowFC){
          selFC.push(rowFC);
          selP.push(rowP);
          sselID.push(rowID);
        }
      });

console.log(sselID)

      var Traces = [];
      var tracePoints = {
        x: selFC,
        y: selP,
        text: sselID,
        mode: 'markers',
        marker: {
          color: 'black',
          size: 6
        },
      };
      Traces.push(tracePoints);
      Plotly.addTraces(el.id, Traces);

      el.on('plotly_selected', function(e) {

      console.log(e.points)
      numSel = e.points.length
      Points = e.points
      selID = []
      for (a=0; a<numSel; a++){
        PN = Points[a].pointNumber
        selRow = sselID[PN]
        selID.push(selRow)
      }
      Shiny.onInputChange('selID', selID);
      })
      }", data = list(dat = dat, thP=threshP(), thFC=threshFC()))})

  selID <- reactive(input$selID)
  selDat <- reactive(dat[which(dat$ID %in% selID()), ])
  output$selectedValues <- renderPrint({selDat()})
  })

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have interesting problems...

I made some small changes to help see what was going on:

- adjusted the init values of the input sliders
- changed the output to a `verbatumTextOutput` of the selection dataframe
- added more information to the tooltip (the ID variable) by including a `text` field in the trace definition.
- printed out the event data the javascript console

From there I could see that frequently (almost always, but not always) there was a kind of dummy point as the first point. Conveniently it always had the `curveNumber` zero

- so I added a guard to exclude it from your selected list.

I think that fixes the problem.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sliderInput("threshP", "P-value:", min = 0, max = 1, value=1, step=0.05),
  sliderInput("threshFC", "Fold change:", min = 0, max = 10, value=0, step=0.5),
  plotlyOutput("plot1"),
  verbatimTextOutput("selectedValues")
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  set.seed(1)
  threshP <- reactive(input$threshP)
  threshFC <- reactive(input$threshFC)

  dat <- data.frame(ID = paste0("ID",1:10), FC=runif(10,0,10), pval=runif(10,0,1))
  dat$ID <- as.character(dat$ID)
  print(dat)

  # x-axis FC, y-axis pval
  xMax = max(dat$FC)
  xMin = min(dat$FC)
  yMax = max(dat$pval)
  yMin = min(dat$pval)

  df <- data.frame()
  p <- ggplot(df) + geom_point() + xlim(xMin, xMax) + ylim(yMin, yMax)
  gp <- ggplotly(p)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    gp %>% onRender("
                    function(el, x, data) {
                    var dat = data.dat
                    var selFC = [];
                    var selP = [];
                    var sselID = [];
                    dat.forEach(function(row){
                    rowFC = row['FC']
                    rowP = row['pval']
                    rowID = row['ID']
                    if (rowP <= data.thP && data.thFC <= rowFC){
                    selFC.push(rowFC);
                    selP.push(rowP);
                    sselID.push(rowID);
                    }
                    });

                    var Traces = [];
                    var tracePoints = {
                    x: selFC,
                    y: selP,
                    text: sselID,
                    mode: 'markers',
                    marker: {
                    color: 'black',
                    size: 6
                    },
                    };
                    Traces.push(tracePoints);
                    Plotly.addTraces(el.id, Traces);

                    var idRows = []
                    for (a=0; a<data.dat.length; a++){
                    idRows.push(data.dat[a]['ID'])
                    }
                    console.log(idRows)

                    el.on('plotly_selected', function(e) {
                      console.log(e.points)
                      numSel = e.points.length
                      Points = e.points
                      selID = []
                      for (a=0; a<numSel; a++){
                      CN = Points[a].curveNumber
                      if (CN>0){
                        PN = Points[a].pointNumber
                        selRow = idRows[PN]
                        selID.push(selRow)
                      } 
                    }
                    Shiny.onInputChange('selID', selID);
                    })
                    }", data = list(dat = dat, thP=threshP(), thFC=threshFC()))})

  selID <- reactive(input$selID)
  selDat <- reactive(dat[which(dat$ID %in% selID()), ])
  output$selectedValues <- renderPrint({selDat()})
  })

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

A screenshot:

[image]

A screenshot of the eventData in the javascript console:

[image]

For those wondering how to get to the javascript console you can:

- right click the R-studio (or browser) shiny window.
- chose "Inspect"
- select the "console" entry
- see the console.log output (you can drill-down into objects)

Comment: Thank you. I like the tooltip text and the verbatumTextOutput. It really helps debug! I think the code you posted still has bugs. I don't think I can attach a screenshot in the comments, but as an example, if I set p-value at 0.55 and fold-change at 0, and the I highlight the three points that have the lowest x-axis values, only 2 of the 3 points are correct.

Comment: Still, thanks to the better debugging with your suggestions, I *think* I figured it out. I am posting the solution in an edit. Thank you again for helping me!

Comment: No problem, curious to what it is too.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. Those point numbers are garbage when you are zoomed. I suppose you could take the point values and hash on that. Maybe round them first.

Comment: Looks like it might be fixed. Will it out later. https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/931